# github search api returns pull request with different merge_commit_sha than the one queried

Tags: github-api

I'm trying to find pull requests based on a list of merge commit sha's using this githup REST api call:

api/v3/search/issues?q=commit_merge_sha=[some_sha]

This query works sometimes, but other times returns a pull request where the actual merge_commit_sha for the pr is not the same as the one i queried for.  Any ideas why this sometimes does not work as expected?